# PySpark unable to access column which was added using StringIndexer

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**PySpark** - v2.4.0

I tried to convert a `String` column `Country` to `Interger` column `Country_ID`, the result looks fine. But when i tried to access the column `Country_ID` i got `AnalysisException`.

Below is the dataframe:

```
+------+-------+
|UserId|Country|
+------+-------+
|     1| Africa|
|     2| Africa|
|     3|     UK|
|     4|  Japan|
|     5|     UK|
|     6|  Japan|
|     7|  China|
+------+-------+
```

Here is the code:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='Country', outputCol='Country_ID')
modified_df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

Modified DataFrame:

```
modified_df.select('*').show()

+------+-------+----------+
|UserId|Country|Country_ID|
+------+-------+----------+
|     1| Africa|       1.0|
|     2| Africa|       1.0|
|     3|     UK|       0.0|
|     4|  Japan|       2.0|
|     5|     UK|       0.0|
|     6|  Japan|       2.0|
|     7|  China|       3.0|
+------+-------+----------+
```

Filter Query:

```
modified_df.select('UserId').filter(df['Country_ID'] == 2).show()
```

Below is the exception:

`AnalysisException: u'Cannot resolve column name "Country_ID" among (UserId, Country);'`

I can see the column as part of DataFrame

```
modified_df.columns
```

gives,

```
['UserId', 'Country', 'Country_ID']
```

How to make the DataFrame filter condition work for `Country_ID`?

Comment: I think if you use `modified_df['Country_ID'] == 2` it should work. You are accessing the column using wrong dataframe reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to access the column using wrong `Dataframe` reference. The column `Country_ID` should be referenced using `modified_df`.

So change

```
modified_df.select('UserId').filter(df['Country_ID'] == 2).show()
```

To

```
modified_df.select('UserId').filter(modified_df['Country_ID'] == 2).show()
```

and it should work. As `df` does not have any column `Country_ID`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks.